# Unable to mount specify location

Tags: mount, mountpoint

I used the same location before but can't mount to the same location after format.

```
mkdir /media/videos
mount /xxxx/by-id/xxx /media/videos # no error message.
rmdir /media/videos # can delete. there is no other process occupying
```

It works if change to other name like

```
mkdir /media/videos2
mount /xxxx/by-id/xxx /media/videos2
```

Checked there is no `/media/videos` or the drive id `/dev/sde1` in the `df` or `/etc/mtab`.

I use the `/etc/fstab` method first and tried to restart multiple times but still not working.

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And provide us more details. We can't help you if you don't provide error messages.

Comment: no error message

Comment: maybe try adding the `-v` / `--verbose` option to your mount command to see if that provides any useful information?

Comment: ... and the output of `findmnt -T /media/videos` before and after might be helpful